# Group array values based on key in Lua?

Tags: algorithm, lua

I have an array:

```
messages = {
    {
        id = 1,
        sender = 987654321,
        content = 'test message'
    },
    {
        id = 2,
        sender = 123456789,
        content = 'testowa wiadomość'
    },
    {
        id = 3,
        sender = 123456789,
        content = 'txd'
    }
}
```

I want to group elements in array based on 'sender' as primary key. Final result should looks like that:

```
messages = {
    {
        sender = 987654321,
        messages = {
            'test message'
        }
    },
    {
        sender = 123456789,
        messages = {
            'testowa wiadomość',
            'txd'
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me out from this please?

Comment: any own attempts/ideas? this is not a free coding service. we help you solve problems. we don't solve them for you. please read [ask]

Comment: I second Piglet. You need to show us that you've attempted to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I solved this problem:

```
function groupMessages(array)
    local result = {};
    for k, v in ipairs(array) do
        if not result[v.sender] then
            result[v.sender] = {};
        end

        table.insert(result[v.sender], v);
    end

   return result;
end
```